# why python multiprocessing initialize same values?

Tags: python, multiprocess

Here is an example

```
import multiprocessing
import numpy as np

def inner_function(idx, return_dic, N):
    c = np.random.choice(N)
    return_dic[idx] = c
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    return_dic = manager.dict()
    jobs = []

    for index in range(10):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(
            target=inner_function, args=(index,return_dic, 10)
        )
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()

    for proc in jobs:
        proc.join()
        
    print(return_dic)
```

the outcome would be the same (e.g., {0: 4, 1: 4, 2: 4, 3: 4, 4: 4, 5: 4, 6: 4, 7: 4, 8: 4, 9: 4}). How to generate random number with multiprocessor?

**Edited:** Problem solved. It seems numpy would treat multiprocessors identically if we want to generate random values. So we would get identical values even we call random functions. We need to manually set the random seed for each processor.

Comment: Please provide a code example that actually shows the problem you are having. The code you provided doesn't make enough sense out of context to be able to answer your question.

Comment: Can you show the contents of `initialize` ?

Comment: The `target` argument should be a reference to a function, not a call to the function.

Comment: `multiprocessing.Process(target=initialize, args=(N,))`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]. In specific, it should be runnable *as is* (no missing imports, no missing guards) and should *clearly output* the result. After adding imports and ``__main__`` guard and ``print(return_dic)``, I cannot reproduce the issue: sample output ``{1: 8, 0: 4, 4: 9, 3: 6, 2: 3, 7: 2, 5: 5, 6: 3, 8: 3, 9: 4}``.

Comment: Please clarify what the expect output is. Running your program several times, I got different output each time. Is that not what the program should do?

Comment: I hope to get your results @MisterMiyagi but somehow I always get the same results and there is no randomness.

Comment: ``{0: 4, 1: 4, 2: 4, 3: 4, 4: 4, 5: 4, 6: 4, 7: 4, 8: 4, 9: 4}`` looks pretty random to me already. Do you by any chance set the ``numpy`` random state, e.g. via ``np.random.seed()``? You might want to check whether ``print(np.random.get_state())`` provides different output on each run.